# Never Ending Story: Twitter Authentication

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, authorization, twitter4j

It seems to be a never ending story, but I cant get access to Twitter from Twitter4J stream API.

1. I created a Twitter Account and changed the timezone to my home country
2. I created an App in Twitter
3. I created a ClientApp in Java/Maven with Twitter4J Streaming API 4.0.0
4. I placed the Api-Key, Secret-Key and the Access-Tokens in the Configuration Builder
5. I get an Exception from Twitter

   ```
   ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
   cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxx");
   cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxx");
   cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxx");

   TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

   StatusListnerImpl statusListenerImpl = new StatusListnerImpl();

   twitterStream.addListener(statusListenerImpl);

   twitterStream.sample();
   ```

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.

Please help.

Comment: Thanks for editing but the credentials i have written were designed only for this post.

Answer (score 1):

For cleaness and simplicity I would recommend creating a separate file under *project_name/resources/twitter4j.properties* with contents:

```
debug=true
##Get the following from https://dev.twitter.com/
oauth.consumerKey=XXX
oauth.consumerSecret=XXX
oauth.accessToken=XXX
oauth.accessTokenSecret=XXX
```

Then you can create a new TwitterStream object as simple as:

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
```

Just make sure the properties file is available at compile time. 
Since you are using maven add the code below in pom.xml file (in build section):

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

PS: you might want to hide your application specific keys/tokens

Comment: thanks for answering. I know that this kind of code is not very clean. It was just for testing. But the outsourcing of the keys and tokens won't solve the problem. After inspecting the http header i recognized that my time and the time of twitter were 5 min apart. Nevertheless Thanks a lot.